# Producing binary matrix with random lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, loops, dictionary

so first of all here is my code I have questions about, I feel like the answer will be simple, but I am just too blind to see it

```
dic = {}

for i in range(0,9):
    dic['rand_num{0}'.format(i)] = np.sort(random.sample(range(0,8),5))

mat = np.zeros([8,8])


for rand_num in dic.values():
    print(rand_num)
    for i in range(0,5):
        matrixval = rand_num[i]
        #print(matrixval)
        for j in range(0,8):
            mat[matrixval,j] = 1


print(mat)
```

I created 8 different lists which will help me determine, where to set a 1 in the matrix.

so eg. if my first list looks like this:

rand_List = [0,3,5,6,7]

the matrix of the first row or column should look like this

matrix = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

My position for the matrix value is set in the second loop: `for i in range(0,5): matrixval = rand_num[i]` . However, as soon I run my code, my matrix just gives me ones instead of ones and zeros. I feel like I have an iteration problem in my last for loop, and I don't know how to fix it.

If anyone could help me, or just give me a hint, how to actually solve this hopefully small mistake of mine, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `matrix = [int(x in rand_list) for x in range(9)]`.

Comment: For a completely random binary matrix you can try: `np.random.randint(0, 2, 8*8).reshape(8,8)`

Comment: @pault Good idea +1 -- will mention tho, `randint` has a `size` param that makes the `.reshape` obsolete. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this provides the expected result:

```
dic = {}

for i in range(0,8):
    dic['rand_num{0}'.format(i)] = np.sort(random.sample(range(0,8),5))

mat = np.zeros([8,8])

for j, rand_num in enumerate(dic.values()):
    print(rand_num)
    for i in range(0,5):
        matrixval = rand_num[i]
        mat[j,matrixval] = 1

print(mat)
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3 5 7]
[0 1 2 5 6]
[0 1 2 3 5]
[1 2 3 4 6]
[0 1 3 4 7]
[1 2 4 5 7]
[0 1 3 4 7]
[1 2 3 4 6]
[[0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dic` you are using is not needed. Here is a solution without it.

```py
import random

lists = []
for i in range(0, 9):
    lists.append(sorted(random.sample(range(0, 8), 5)))

mat = []
for lst in lists:
    arr = [0] * 8

    for index in lst:
        arr[index] = 1

    mat.append(arr)

print(mat)
```

Outputs:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

---

You can also use [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint) to generate your binary 2d array.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(2, size=(8, 8))
print(arr)
```

Outputs:

```
[[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have not thought about that, definitely another way of solving this!

Comment: Sometimes it is best not to reinvent the wheel.